# Critérios de consulta com caracter coringa

Tags: php, query

Estou tentando usar caracter coringa como critério de consulta na minha query, porém o resultado está retornado vazio.

include_once("../inc/conexao.php");

```
$lj = "4";
$linha      = isset($_GET['ans'])?$_GET['ans']:"";
$data   = date("d-m-Y");
$partes = explode("-", $data);
$ano    = $partes[2];
$periodo = "$ano%";


$sql = "SELECT sjy_vendas.tipo, Sum(sjy_vendas.qt) AS qt, Sum(sjy_vendas.qtv) AS qtv, Sum(sjy_vendas.rprd) AS rprd, Sum(sjy_vendas.rsrv) AS rsrv, Sum(sjy_vendas.tprd) AS tprd, Sum(sjy_vendas.tsrv) AS tsrv, Sum(sjy_vendas.vlr_compra) AS vlr_compra
FROM sjy_vendas
WHERE sjy_vendas.empresa = $lj 
AND sjy_vendas.tipo = $linha
AND dt_nf CONCAT('%',:param,'%')
GROUP BY sjy_vendas.tipo";
$sql->bindParam(':param',$ano);
$consulta   = mysqli_query($conexao,$sql);
while($dados = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta)){

$qtv    = $dados['qtv'];
$rprd   = $dados['rprd'];

}

echo "Quantidade: " . $qtv . "<br />";
echo "Receita: " . $rprd . "<br />";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Altere a variável sql para uma chamada de função  mysqli_prepare passando a string sql como parâmetro depois use a função msqli_bind_param para anexar o parâmetro $ano. 
Segue um exemplo, terá que adaptar para  funcionar de acordo com suas necessidades:

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
$sql = mysqli_prepare($link, "SELECT sjy_vendas.tipo, Sum(sjy_vendas.qt) AS qt, Sum(sjy_vendas.qtv) AS qtv, Sum(sjy_vendas.rprd) AS rprd, Sum(sjy_vendas.rsrv) AS rsrv, Sum(sjy_vendas.tprd) AS tprd, Sum(sjy_vendas.tsrv) AS tsrv, Sum(sjy_vendas.vlr_compra) AS vlr_compra
FROM sjy_vendas
WHERE sjy_vendas.empresa = $lj 
AND sjy_vendas.tipo = $linha
AND dt_nf CONCAT('%',:param,'%')
GROUP BY sjy_vendas.tipo""));
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($sql, "s", $ano);
```

Informações mais detalhadas neste link: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.prepare.php

Answer (score 0):

Se o problema for a concatenação da string '%' na váriavel do parâmetro,você pode tentar como no exemplo a seguir usando a função CONCAT do SQL:

```
$sql = "SELECT item_title FROM item WHERE item_title LIKE CONCAT('%',:param,'%')";
$sql->bindParam(':param', $paramentro );
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta Evandro, mas agora está retornando o erro Fatal error: Call to a member function bindParam() on a non-object in D:\xampp\htdocs\final\views\premorc.php on line 2705. Vou editar a pergunta para colocar o código que eu estou usando.